# cut with 2 character delimiter

Tags: awk, cut

I wanted to use cut to with a 2 charachter delimeter to process a file with many lines like this:

```
1F3C6..1F3CA
1F3CF..1F3D3
1F3E0..1F3F0
```

*But cut only allows a single character.*

Instead of `cut -d'..'` I'm trying `awk -F'..' "{echo $1}"` but it's not working.

**My script:**

```
wget -O output.txt http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/6.0/emoji-data.txt                                                                             
sed -i '/^#/ d' output.txt                        # Remove comments                                                                                   
cat output.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | while read line ;                                                                                                    
  do echo $line | awk -F'..' "{echo $1}"                                                                                                             
done
```

Comment: Can `.` appear alone elsewhere in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample test script that works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

raw="1F3C6..1F3CA
1F3CF..1F3D3
1F3E0..1F3F0"

for r in $raw
do
    f1=`echo "${r}" | cut -d'.' -f1`
    f2=`echo "${r}" | cut -d'.' -f2`
    f3=`echo "${r}" | cut -d'.' -f3`
    echo "field 1:[${f1}] field 2:[${f2}] field 3:[${f3}]"
done

exit
```

And the output is:

```
field 1:[1F3C6] field 2:[] field 3:[1F3CA]
field 1:[1F3CF] field 2:[] field 3:[1F3D3]
field 1:[1F3E0] field 2:[] field 3:[1F3F0]
```

**Edit**

After reading Stéphane Chazelas comment and linked Q&A, I re-wrote the above to remove the `loop`.

I could not work out a way to remove the `loop` *and* keep the parts as variables (for example; `$f1`, `$f2` and `$f3` in my original answer) that could be passed around. Still I don't know what was required output in the original question.

First, still using `cut`:

```
#!/bin/sh
raw="1F3C6..1F3CA
1F3CF..1F3D3
1F3E0..1F3F0"

printf '%s\n' "${raw}" | cut -d'.' -f1,3
```

Which will output:

```
1F3C6.1F3CA
1F3CF.1F3D3
1F3E0.1F3F0
```

Could replace the displayed `.` with any string using the `--output-delimiter=STRING`.

Next, with `sed` instead of `cut` in order to give more control of the output:

```
#!/bin/sh
raw="1F3C6..1F3CA
1F3CF..1F3D3
1F3E0..1F3F0"

printf '%s\n' "${raw}" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\.\.\(.*\)$/field 1 [\1] field 2 [\2]/'
```

And this will render:

```
field 1 [1F3C6] field 2 [1F3CA]
field 1 [1F3CF] field 2 [1F3D3]
field 1 [1F3E0] field 2 [1F3F0]
```

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Read the linked Q&A, thanks. A lot to learn clearly.

Comment: Not an answer. They asked how to use multicharacter and this explains how to use single character. What if they are trying to avoid reserved characters in Bash? This just had them split their path apart at the `./`, especially if it's not fixed width.

Answer (score 14):

`awk`'s field separator is treated as a regexp as long as it's more than two characters. `..` as a regexp, means any 2 characters. You'd need to escape that `.` either with `[.]` or with `\.`.

```
awk -F'[.][.]' ...
awk -F'\\.\\.' ...
```

(the backslash itself also needs to be escaped (with some awks like gawk at least) for the `\n`/`\b` expansion that the argument to `-F` undergoes).

In your case:

```
awk -F' +|[.][.]' '/^[^#]/{print $1}' < output.txt
```

In any case, [avoid shell loops to process text](/q/169716), note that [`read` is not meant to be used like that](/q/209123), that [`echo` should not be used for arbitrary data](/q/65803) and [remember to quote your variables](/q/171346).

Answer (score 2):

You could use IFS to split each line discarding the field between the two dots:

```
#/bin/sh
while IFS=\. read a _ b
do
     echo "field one=[$a] field two=[$b]"
done < "file"
```

Execute:

```
$ ./script
field one=1F3C6 field two=1F3CA
field one=1F3CF field two=1F3D3
field one=1F3E0 field two=1F3F0
```

Assuming that file is:

```
$ cat file
1F3C6..1F3CA
1F3CF..1F3D3
1F3E0..1F3F0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rev` to revert your string:

```
cat data.txt
1F3C6..1F3CA
1F3CF..1F3D3
1F3E0..1F3F0
```

First column:

```
cat data.txt | cut -d. -f1
1F3C6
1F3CF
1F3E0
```

Last column:

```
cat data.txt | rev | cut -d. -f1 | rev
1F3CA
1F3D3
1F3F0
```

Unfortunately this method would work in your case only and not acceptable for wider species of input data.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00001.html) that adds new `-m` command-line option to `cut`, which works in the field mode and treats multiple consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.  This basically solves the OP's question in a rather efficient way.  I also submitted this patch upstream a couple of days ago, and let's hope that it will be merged into the coreutils project.

There are some [further thoughts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00011.html) about adding even more whitespace-related features to `cut`, and having some feedback about all that would be great.  I'm willing to implement more patches for `cut` and submit them upstream, which would make this utility more versatile and more usable in various real-world scenarios.